# Convert Sizes in numbers

Tags: python, dataframe

In a dataframe, in a specific columns I have values of sizes like 19M, 2.8M. M means millions and so on with the other possibilities (`m, K.`).

I'm trying to convert these into numbers with regex but what the function converts is in numbers like 19000000.0. I have to eliminate all the `.0`.

Here the code:

```
conversion = re.compile('(?P<amount>\d+\.{0,1}\d*)(?P<unit>\w{0,1})')

def unita(unit):

    if unit == 'M':
        return 1000000
    if unit == 'k':
        return 1000
    return 1

def to_numeric(elem):
    m = conversion.search(elem)
    if m is None:
        return None
    unit = m.group('unit')
    mult = unita(unit)
    amount = float(m.group('amount'))
    return int(amount * mult)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the columns in the dataframe that you want to convert to integers, use

```
df['column'] = df['column'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Even better is to use the recent `df['column'].astype('Int64')`, which is an integer type which allows NaNs and Nones in the column as well, without failing to convert.